# Get a Token without using Accept.js

Tags: authorize.net

For testing purpose, I'd like to get a token to process a payment without using Accept.js because I want to do some tests with Postman and on the backend side.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to get a token to process payments without using Accept.js and it is very easy. See : https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Ideas/Test-Opaque-Token/idc-p/59455#M452 for an example.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer, but I do not have the time right now to test it. Will come back  if I get some issues.